# Spring Boot Native Query returns different Resultset when executing directly in SQL Navigator

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using a native query to get a specific resulset since there's a conflict when using LIMIT in JPA. When I call the method via spring-boot I get 1 row but when I execute the SQL command directly I get 5 rows. I think this is a JPA native query issue it's always returning 1 row.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT\n" + 
        "   DISTINCT pt1.******\n" + 
        "    FROM\n" + 
        "        ***** ptvt1 \n" + 
        "    INNER JOIN\n" + 
        "        **** pt1     \n" + 
        "            ON ptvt1.****** = pt1.id \n" + 
        "    WHERE\n" + 
        "        pt1.id IN      (\n" + 
        "            SELECT\n" + 
        "                ptvt2.******         \n" + 
        "            FROM\n" + 
        "                ***** ptvt2         \n" + 
        "            INNER JOIN\n" + 
        "                ***** pt2             \n" + 
        "                    ON ptvt2.****** = pt2.id         \n" + 
        "            WHERE\n" + 
        "                ptvt2.******** = ptvt1.********         \n" + 
        "            ORDER BY\n" + 
        "                pt2.executiondate DESC         LIMIT 1     \n" + 
        "        )     \n" + 
        "        AND NOT EXISTS     (\n" + 
        "            SELECT\n" + 
        "                ptvt3.*         \n" + 
        "            FROM\n" + 
        "                ***** ptvt3         \n" + 
        "            INNER JOIN\n" + 
        "                ***** pt3             \n" + 
        "                    ON ptvt3.****** = pt3.id         \n" + 
        "            WHERE\n" + 
        "                ptvt3.******** = ptvt1.********             \n" + 
        "                AND (\n" + 
        "                    pt3.status = 'OK'                 \n" + 
        "                    OR pt3.status = 'CREATED'                 \n" + 
        "                    OR pt3.status = 'PENDING'                 \n" + 
        "                    OR pt3.status = 'VOID'             \n" + 
        "                )     \n" + 
        "        )", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> find*****();
```

Comment: Updated it but I have to mask out the columns though.

Comment: List<String> find*****()

Comment: I don't the LIMIT 1 should affect it since it's a subquery that's the reason why I'm using nativeQuery in the first place.